# Find wrong records of fields that can only change upwards

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+--+----------+--------+-----+---+
|id|date      |machine |start|end|
+--+----------+--------+-----+---+
| 1|2017-05-24|Machine1|  100|109|
| 2|2017-05-24|Machine2|  550|560|
| 3|2017-05-25|Machine1|  108|116|
| 4|2017-05-26|Machine1|  116|124|
| 5|2017-05-26|Machine2|  570|580|
+--+----------+--------+-----+---+
```

The start and end fields are the hour counter of each machine. The counters can only go up. In the row with id 3, the start value of Machine1 is less than the end value of Machine1 in the row with id 1.

Is there a way to query to return all rows with errors?

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.first_thing is the same as x.first_thing AND y.second_thing is bigger than x.second_thing AND y.third_thing is smaller than x.third_thing

Comment: can you post the output of your `show CREATE table table_name;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will scan all rows in order and check each against the previous:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    IF(machine = @last_machine AND @last_end > `start`, @last_id, null) as wrong_pair_id,
    @last_machine := machine as __t1,
    @last_end := `end` as __t2,
    @last_id := id as __t3
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY machine, `date`
) t
JOIN (SELECT @last_id := null, @last_end:=null, @last_machine:=null) as i
HAVING wrong_pair_id IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to select the pairs of rows you can wrap this in another SELECT and join on the wrong_pair_id

Comment: `@last_id := id as __t3 should be after @last_end line?`

Comment: Yes, I missed that one